# Executing SQL Server stored procedure in sql squirrel

Tags: sql-server, squirrel-sql

i'm in ubuntu 9.04 and using sql squirrel as my sql client. i connect to a remote SQL Server. There are some stored procedures in the db. I don't know how to execute them. No explicit gui. Earlier i was in windows and i could use management studio. I can right click on stored procedures and give Execute. You guys have any idea? Let me know. It will be helpful for me. :)

Comment: Can I suggest an edit to the Question title to replace "SQL Server" with "MSSQL Server" or "Microsoft SQL Server" to reduce confusion and make it clear which server this is for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, if you want to execute a SQL Server stored procedure, you'd write:

```
EXEC Your-stored-proc-name-here @param1 = value1, @param2 = value2
```

and then execute that command. Typically, you should also use the `dbo.StoredProcName` notation to avoid any confusion / problems.

Comment: I had problems using the parenthesis. But managed to execute with exec **procname**, the rest is the same

Comment: additionaly, if you have output parameters, you need to declare them. tried to use examples but SO don't accept '@'

Answer (score 3):

```
EXEC <STOREDPROCNAME> <PARAMLIST>

EXEC dbo.GetCandy 'Red',62
```

Then hit execute or the equivalent in your editor.

Comment: DARN - beat me by 51 seconds! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had to tweak it slightly for a Microsoft SQL Server database (jsqlconnect driver). This worked for me:

```
execute <sproc_name> <args>
```